# expression.call value cannot be null

Tags: vb.net, linq, expression-trees

I'm trying to code this LINQ query with expression trees:

```
Result = Result.Where(Function(Row) Convert.ToInt32(Row(2)) <= 10)
```

`Result` is declared as `Dim Result As IEnumerable(Of Object())`.

I have this code so far:

```
Dim queryiabledata As IQueryable(Of Object()) = Result.AsQueryable

Dim pe As ParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(GetType(String), "Row(2)")
Dim left As expression = Expression.Call(pe, GetType(String).GetMethod("Convert.ToInt32", System.Type.EmptyTypes))
Dim right As Expression = Expression.Constant(10)
Dim e1 As Expression = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(left, right)

Dim predicatebody As Expression = e1
Dim wherecallexpression As MethodCallExpression = Expression.Call(
    GetType(Queryable), "Where", New Type() {queryiabledata.ElementType}, queryiabledata.Expression,
    Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of Object(), Boolean))(predicatebody, New ParameterExpression() {pe}))

Result = queryiabledata.Provider.CreateQuery(Of Object())(wherecallexpression)
```

But if I run the query, I get an ArgumentNullException (Value cannot be null. Parameter name: method) at `Expression.Call`.

I tried to change `"Convert.ToInt32"` to `"Value"`, but I got the same error.

How can I fix it?

Are the another code lines right to get the desired result?

Comment: Have you tried to add an if statement before using the value to check if it's null? Example: if(Result.Where(Function(Row) Convert.ToInt32(Row(2)) <= 10) != null){Result = Result.Where(Function(Row) Convert.ToInt32(Row(2)) <= 10)}

Comment: I have not with this problem. I have problem with calling the method Convert.ToInt32. It seems, that the method cannot be found. I do surely what wrong, but I don't know yet, what. The expression trees are new to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm more used to C#, though I do VB.NET occasionally. Reflection in VB.NET is downright ugly. Getting the `Where` method is a bit of a hack. Here's the code:

`shortForm` and `longForm` should be identical.

```
    Dim result As IEnumerable(Of Object()) = New List(Of Object())()
    Dim queryiabledata As IQueryable(Of Object()) = result.AsQueryable()
    Dim shortForm As Expression = queryiabledata.Where(Function(Row) Convert.ToInt32(Row(2)) <= 10).Expression

    Dim whereMethod = GetType(Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Static).
        First(Function(m) m.Name = "Where").
        MakeGenericMethod(GetType(Object()))
    Dim convertMethod = GetType(System.Convert).GetMethod("ToInt32", New Type() {GetType(Object)})
    Dim rowParameter = Expression.Parameter(GetType(Object()), "Row")

    Dim longform As Expression =
        Expression.Call(
            whereMethod,
            queryiabledata.Expression,
            Expression.Lambda(
                Expression.LessThanOrEqual(
                    Expression.Call(
                            convertMethod,
                            Expression.ArrayAccess(
                                rowParameter,
                                Expression.Constant(2)
                            )
                        ),
                    Expression.Constant(10)
                ),
                rowParameter
            )
        )
    result = queryiabledata.Provider.CreateQuery(longform)
```

Answer (score 0):

This line seems suspect to me:

```
GetType(String).GetMethod("Convert.ToInt32", System.Type.EmptyTypes)
```

`GetType(String)` returns the runtime type String.  You then try to get a method called "Convert.ToInt32" which doesn't exist on the string type.  I suspect that is returning null which is the source of your exception.

Perhaps you need to use something like this:

```
GetType(Convert).GetMethod("ToInt32", new Type() {GetType(Object)})
```

Since there are multiple overloads of the `ToInt32` method of the `Convert` class, you need to specify which of the overloads you want by providing an array of `Type` as the second parameter.  In other words, you a saying "give me the overload that takes an Object type as it's parameter".

Comment: Thanks to you too for the explanation.